# Insert statement not working in MYSQL for variables generated on the same page

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I need your help with my script. What I'm trying t do is insert values into mysql, wereby $row['senatorial'] and $constituencys are entered simultaneously. The coe below is wa I'm trying to make work but it's not working. No error i shown on the screen and nothing is entered into the database.
Please where am I going wrong

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == "submit") {

  $state  = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['state']));

  $query = mysql_query("SELECT senatorial              
                    FROM state
                    WHERE state = '".$state."'") or die (mysql_error());

  $duplicates = mysql_num_rows($query);

  if (isset($_POST['constituency']) && $_POST['action'] == "create") {


    $constituencys = $_POST['constituency'];
    foreach($constituencys as $constituency) {
      $query = "
                    INSERT INTO  `state` (
                    `state_id`,
                    `state`,
                    `senatorial`
                    `constituency`
                    ) VALUES (
                    NULL,
                    '{$state}',
                    '{$row['senatorial']}',
                    '" . mysql_real_escape_string(trim($constituency)) . "'
                    )
                    ";
      mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

    }
  } ?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] ?>" method="post">
  <?php

  while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    echo strtoupper($row['senatorial']) ;?>
    <input type='text' name='constituency[]' title='Federal Constituency' />
    <?php  } ;?>
  <input type="hidden" name="create" value="create" />
  <input type='submit' name='create' value='Create' />
</form>
<?php } ?>

<h2>Select State To show Senatorial Districts</h2>
<form  action="<?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] ?>" method="post">
  State:<select name="state" title='State'  class='OpenInput_Select'>
  <option value ="">    </option>
  <option value ="state1">state1</option></select>
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit" />
  <input type='submit' name='submit' value='SHOW' />
</form>
```

Comment: Add some `echo` calls here and there to check the program flow. Also add `print_r` of relevant variables.

Comment: you have this line in html: `<input type='text' name='constituency[]' title='Federal Constituency' />`. Then, you try to access it directly as an array, in PHP, using the $_POST? How is the user supposed to insert values in that text input?

Comment: i think problem is here " {$state}', '{$row['senatorial']}' " if you are using smarty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This if statement:

```
if (isset($_POST['constituency']) && $_POST['action'] == "create")
```

is inside this if statement:

```
if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == "submit")
```

So, $_POST['action'] cannot be "submit" and "create" at the same time so you will never get to your INSERT.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. Now, I've changed the name attribute for the second if statement to create. Still nothing showing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == "submit") {
    $state  = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['state']));
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT senatorial              
                    FROM state
                    WHERE state = '".$state."'") or die (mysql_error());

    $duplicates = mysql_num_rows($query);
}

if (isset($_POST['constituency']) && $_POST['action'] == "create") {
    $constituencys = $_POST['constituency'];
    foreach($constituencys as $constituency) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO  `state` (
                `state_id`,
                `state`,
                `senatorial`
                `constituency`
                ) VALUES (
                NULL,
                '{$state}',
                '{$row['senatorial']}',
                '" . mysql_real_escape_string(trim($constituency)) . "'
                )";
        mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
    }
}
```

**I recommend to start using `mysqli_*` functions or PDO extension instead of `mysql_*`...**

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It's not inserting still. I've also changed the name attribute for the second if to create.

Thanks